# Clean + Sand = Modified?

Tags: foundation, stone, retaining-wall

I have about a yard of sand and a yard of clean crushed stone left over from a project. For another project - a 12-18" high stone garden wall - I need about a yard of modified crushed stone. Can I kill three birds with one stone and mix the clean crushed stone with the sand to make an approximation of modified crushed stone? Will it be as effective for a foundation of the garden wall?

Comment: You need to find the specification for the "modified crush stone" to find out the proportion of each aggregate to achieve the goal - densification yey permeable.

Comment: You're just some Portland cement away from having concrete mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two types of often-used base materials for your information. You can get details from [here](https://unionquarries.com/products/aggregate-types/#:%7E:text=2A%20stone%3A%20Also%20known%20as%202A%20crushed%20stone,a%20sub-base%20for%20roadways%2C%20walking%20paths%20and%20driveways.), and [here](https://www.dirtandgravel.psu.edu/sites/default/files/General%20Resources/Technical%20Bulletins/TB_Aggregate_101.pdf).

[image]

PennDOT 2A has a 2 inch top size and many fines. Great compaction and used as a road base and under slabs. Primarily a clean material that will compact and will drain. Used where stability and drainability are concerns.

[image]

Material has a 2 inch top size and is a mix of coarse stone and fine material. Fines in material will include dirt, silt, loam, or clay Great compaction and is used under slabs, road base, and fill. Primarily a dirty material that will compact and does not drain.

Note: The name Crushed Stone and Crushed Gravel are interchangeable, they are both processed materials.

Answer (score 0):

No. Sand will not emulate modified crushed stone.

Understand what modified crushed stone is... Modified crushed stone has smaller stone in it to help lock together the larger stone and create a smoother surface.

There is no such thing is modified gravel because gavel grew in the water and has a smooth rounded surface. Where a rounded surface is, there is no interlocking and a solid surface cannot be created.

The sand came out of the water too. It has not been crushed to create random flat surfaces everywhere. It is rounded and very small and will simply rinse to the bottom of the crushed stone.

The moving of the sand to the bottom of the stone will not be harmful, but it will not serve a purpose either. It will not help hold the crushed stone together. In fact, it may keep the crushed stone apart from each other which will help retain a soft surface. All depends upon what you want, but sand + crushed stone is not modified crushed stone.